# fluentd + eks: skipping to send logs of jobs running for a few seconds

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

I'm having an issue with `fluentd 1.13/1.14` where it's not forwarding log messages of k8s `Jobs` to cloudwatch if the job runs just for a few seconds. For long-running jobs it works just fine.

#### Fluentd config:

```
<source>
    @type tail
    @label @container
    path /var/log/containers/*.log
    exclude_path ["/var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*", "/var/log/containers/fluentd*"]
    pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
    tag container.*
    read_from_head true
    follow_inodes true
    <parse>
        @type multi_format
        <pattern>
            format cri
            time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
            format json
            time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
        </pattern>
    </parse>
</source>
```

It seems that `fluentd` is detecting the log files but it's not forwarding it at all. It's also a bit weird that it detects log rotation on a file that is so small (5 log lines)

#### Fluentd Logs:

```
2021-12-02 18:46:47 +0000 [info]: #0 [Aws::CloudWatchLogs::Client 200 0.020815 0 retries] put_log_events(log_events:[{timestamp:1638470804512,message:"[FILTERED]"}],log_group_name:"/convox/rrr/system",log_stream_name:"service/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-788976446-wwbg5",sequence_token:"49605556107201490919304478315024039166400664032086327554")  

2021-12-02 18:46:49 +0000 [info]: #0 following tail of /var/log/containers/timer-test-timer-1638470760-zdjjw_rrr-logtest3_logtest3-34477acc21d8d5f7bf8a40ebee9066f6f1184be99f1f8c10abd1452a4c885b64.log
2021-12-02 18:46:51 +0000 [info]: #0 detected rotation of /var/log/containers/timer-test-timer-1638470760-zdjjw_rrr-logtest3_logtest3-34477acc21d8d5f7bf8a40ebee9066f6f1184be99f1f8c10abd1452a4c885b64.log; waiting 5.0 seconds
2021-12-02 18:47:49 +0000 [info]: #0 following tail of /var/log/containers/timer-test-timer-1638470820-p4sgb_rrr-logtest3_logtest3-42e07d8720bad119c779b29b3a65fdde38b0116f19085f333973bc169064d537.log
2021-12-02 18:47:51 +0000 [info]: #0 detected rotation of /var/log/containers/timer-test-timer-1638470820-p4sgb_rrr-logtest3_logtest3-42e07d8720bad119c779b29b3a65fdde38b0116f19085f333973bc169064d537.log; waiting 5.0 seconds
```

I tried playing with `read_from_head` and `follow_inodes` values but it doesn't work. if anything it just stops detecting log rotation on the file

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by changing [refresh_interval](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail#refresh_interval) to 1 second. From my understanding, the problem occurred because the job would run for 20 seconds and have the log file removed before the default `tail` refresh interval(60 seconds) so the file was never tailed. I did some tests on performance to make sure it wouldn't impact fluentd pod's resource consumption and everything seemed fine.